# C# Decoding QRCODE in real image using ZXING.NET

Tags: c#, computer-vision, qr-code, zxing, decoding

I'm trying to reading QR CODES in the images acquired by an usb camera.
In other posts I have read that the best open source library is ZXing.

If the qrcode comes from a digitally generated image the library works fine, but if the qrcode comes from a real case where the image is acquired by a camera the deconding library has some difficulties.

The acquired images are disturbed by some glare, or code deformation, or slow contrast.

Do you know some parameters to setup better the reader?
Or some filter to add to the image before elaboration?

For example:

```
BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();

reader.AutoRotate = true;
reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
reader.Options.PureBarcode = false;
reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>();
reader.Options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);

var result = reader.Decode(image);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

After several test the best result for 300dpi scanned image comes with :

```
//use gaussian filter to remove noise
var gFilter = new GaussianBlur(2);
image = gFilter.ProcessImage(image);
                   
var options = new DecodingOptions { PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE }, TryHarder = true };
    
using (image)
{
    //use GlobalHistogramBinarizer for best result
    var reader = new BarcodeReader(null, null, ls => new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(ls)) { AutoRotate = false, TryInverted = false, Options = options };
    var result = reader.Decode(image);
    reader = null;
                    
   return result;
}
```

For gaussian filter I use this code from http://www.cnblogs.com/Dah/archive/2007/03/30/694527.html

Hope this help someone.